# Load data from CSV file (data seperated by pipe "|") into a table using SQL loader when the data present in double quotes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I am loading CSV file data into table called EMPLOYEE using SQL*Loader.

My CSV file data is separated by pipe (|):

```
EMPID|EMPNAME_ADDRESS|SALARY|GRADE
123|Rams Hyd|1000|A1
124|Sand MUM|2,000|A2
125|"PRASANNA qwer trasf\"501 advv vvd, qee ggg\trfe        \411005       THE|3,00,000|A3
```

and my control file is:

```
LOAD DATA
Insert INTO TABLE EMPLOYEE
Fields terminated by "|" Optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
   EMPID,
   EMPNAME,
   SALARY,
   GRADE
)
```

When I load the data using above control file, the first two record are loading fine and for the third record i am getting error like as mentioned below.

```
no terminator found after TERMINATED and ENCLOSED field
```

Please suggest changes to be done to load the data properly.

Comment: None of the fields seem to actually be enclosed by double-quotes - the third just happens to contain some... so why do you have the `optionally enclosed by` clause at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to load such data.

First, a target table (I hope it makes sense; you should have provided it):

```
SQL> create table employee
  2  (empid   number,
  3   empname varchar2(200),
  4   salary  number,
  5   grade   varchar2(10)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Control file: note the `SKIP` option (which skips the header line), as well as `REPLACE` function call for the SALARY column (to remove superfluous commas which are *formatting* stuff; add them later, in the *presentation* layer).

```
options (skip = 1)
load data 
infile *
replace
into table employee
fields terminated by "|" TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
empid,
empname,
salary "replace(:salary, ',', null)",
grade)

begindata
EMPID|EMPNAME_ADDRESS|SALARY|GRADE
123|Rams Hyd|1000|A1
124|Sand MUM|2,000|A2
125|"PRASANNA qwer trasf\"501 advv vvd, qee ggg\trfe        \411005       THE|3,00,000|A3
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger control=test06.ctl log=test06.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Uto Tra 9 19:37:46 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2
Commit point reached - logical record count 3

SQL> select * From employee;

     EMPID EMPNAME                                      SALARY GRADE
---------- ---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
       123 Rams Hyd                                       1000 A1
       124 Sand MUM                                       2000 A2
       125 "PRASANNA qwer trasf\"501 advv vvd, qee      300000 A3
           ggg\trfe        \411005       THE


SQL>
```